# How to specify svg linear gradient in terms of an angle

Tags: css, svg, gradient

I'd like to specify an SVG linear gradient in a way that exactly duplicates CSS linear-gradient behavior. In a CSS gradient, for example, you may specify that a gradient start and end at the top left and bottom right of a box respectively. When a box resizes, the background gradient adapts automatically to the new size.

In my first attempt, I duplicated a CSS linear-gradient with SVG, by specifying an angle and by calculating the x1,y1,x2,y2 coordinates from the box size. But if the box is resized, the angle of the gradient does not change and is no longer correct. (I would have to recalc all the coordinates).

My next attempt was to use a transform to rotate the gradient. Here's some code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <linearGradient id="g1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
      gradientTransform="rotate(-45 150 50)">
    <stop stop-color="#FF0000" offset="0"/>
    <stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0.5"/>
    <stop stop-color="#0000FF" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g1)" />
</svg>
```

Now, this works for a box of size (300,100) but you'll see that I'm having to specify absolute values for the centre of rotation (150,50).

Can I specify the centre in terms of a percentage? In the end I want the angle of the gradient to adapt to the dimensions of the box.

Comment: Is gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="rotate(-45 0.5 0.5)" what you're looking for?

Comment: I think I've tried that because I started out using objectBoundingBox but I'll give it another try...

Comment: I just tried it again and it doesn't work. What it appears to do is calculate the rotated gradient on a square box, so for -45 it goes from one corner to another. Then it appears to stretch the width, leaving the gradient as is. If the box was 100x100 then the angle would be correct, but in my example, the angle ends up wrong.

Comment: Interestingly, you stated on your first attempt "the angle of the gradient does not change" when your rect is resized in SVG. That's exactly what I am wanting to do, but can't quite figure it out. Can you share your code on how you did that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG only allows gradient transform rotation origins to be [specified in terms of absolute coordinates](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute). You will need to set the rotation origin dynamically with JavaScript in order to do what I think you're looking to do: which is to rotate the gradient, but also have the color stops be evenly distributed within the containing box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I'm trying to do is exactly mimic the CSS linear-gradient. All the examples on the net use a gradient specified in terms of a side or corner origin. This is easy to mimic in svg and the effect will not change if the box is resized. A CSS gradient specified in terms of an angle can also be mimicked by either calculating the x1,y1,x2,y2 coordinates or rotating about the centre. The problem occurs when the box is resized. To be clear, are you saying that when the box is resized the coordinates must be recalculated in order to maintain parity with a CSS gradient?